# Ruta de Archivos para JasperReport en Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, rutas, jasper-reports

estoy tratando de generar el reporte a través de mi computador y si funciona correctamente, pero cuando compilo el programa y lo paso hacía otra computadora no me detecta el archivos .jasper para generar el reporte, he intentado cambiar la ruta del archivo, pero no podido lograr que funcione en otro computador. gracias de antemano.

```
        InputStream jasper = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/JasperReports/PA.jasper");
        Connection Conexion = null;

        try {

            Conexion = MySQL.getConexion();

            JasperPrint JP = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, null, Conexion);
            JasperViewer JV = new JasperViewer(JP);
            JV.setVisible(true);

            Conexion.close();

        } catch (JRException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error al intentar visualizar el JasperReport", "Control de Estudio", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ha ocurrido un error al intentar cargar los datos al JasperReport", "Control de Estudio", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: Hola Héctor, yo probaría: **try { InputStream jasper = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/JasperReports/PA.jasper" ); } catch( Exception e ) { System.out.print( "fallo" ); }**, de esa forma comprobás si la ruta en la que están los archivos es la correcta.

Comment: Si no compartes el error que tienes es dificil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Disculpa, pero gracias a @MarcePuente pude encontrar el error en el archivo .jrmxl del JasperReport la ruta de las imagenes que tiene el PDF las tengo que cambiar porque están asignados a mi computador y no al archivo jar